# How to remove CDATA without removing the element which doesn't contain CDATA?

Tags: xslt, cdata

While removing CDATA with the below XSLT some element is getting removed where CDATA is not present.

Can someone throw some light on the code? Where I am making mistake. Thanks.

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response status="200">
    <CrsCreateCourseExpResponse>
        <pCategoryOut>
            <![CDATA[<XX_IL_OLM_CRS_CAT_TAB_OBJ>Y<XX_IL_OLM_CRS_CAT_TAB_OBJ>]]>
        </pCategoryOut>
        <pLearnerAccessOut>
            <![CDATA[<XX_IL_OLM_LRNR_ACC_TAB_OBJ><P_OLM_LRNR_ACC_ERRORS>N</P_OLM_LRNR_ACC_ERRORS></XX_IL_OLM_LRNR_ACC_TAB_OBJ>]]>
        </pLearnerAccessOut>
        <pActivityVersionId>42002</pActivityVersionId>
        <pOvn>1</pOvn>
        <pErrorCode>0</pErrorCode>
        <pErrorMsg>success</pErrorMsg>
    </CrsCreateCourseExpResponse>
</response>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response status="200">
    <XX_IL_OLM_CRS_CAT_TAB_OBJ>Y<XX_IL_OLM_CRS_CAT_TAB_OBJ>
            <XX_IL_OLM_LRNR_ACC_TAB_OBJ>
                <P_OLM_LRNR_ACC_ERRORS>N</P_OLM_LRNR_ACC_ERRORS>
            </XX_IL_OLM_LRNR_ACC_TAB_OBJ>
            4200210success
            </response>
```

Desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response status="200">
    <CrsCreateCourseExpResponse>
        <pCategoryOut>
            <XX_IL_OLM_CRS_CAT_TAB_OBJ>Y<XX_IL_OLM_CRS_CAT_TAB_OBJ>
        </pCategoryOut>
        <pLearnerAccessOut>
            <XX_IL_OLM_LRNR_ACC_TAB_OBJ><P_OLM_LRNR_ACC_ERRORS>N</P_OLM_LRNR_ACC_ERRORS></XX_IL_OLM_LRNR_ACC_TAB_OBJ>
        </pLearnerAccessOut>
        <pActivityVersionId>42002</pActivityVersionId>
        <pOvn>1</pOvn>
        <pErrorCode>0</pErrorCode>
        <pErrorMsg>success</pErrorMsg>
    </CrsCreateCourseExpResponse>
</response>
```

XSLT I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="name/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
    <Language>English</Language>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any `name` element in the input so the use of `<xsl:template match="name/text()">` is not clear to me, however instead of the template `<xsl:template match="*">` you could simply use `<xsl:template match="text()"><xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/></xsl:template>` to make sure disable-output-escaping is applied when copying all text nodes, if you don't need it for all of them then restrict it to e.g. `<xsl:template match="pCategoryOut/text() | pLearnerAccessOut/text()"><xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/></xsl:template>`. Then remove the `template match="*"`, the first template, the identity transformation template, will take care of copying elements.